# Reading a text file into a 2d list in Python, without deleting spaces

Tags: python

So I'm working on a project for school and we will be given a text file similar to the one shown here:

```
+---+-----+-----+
|   |     |     |
|   |     |     |
|   |     +=====+
+---+     |  |  |
|   |     |  |  |
|   +-+   +=====+
|   | |   |     |
|   | +-+ |     |
|   |   | |     |
|   |   +-+     |
|   |     |_____|
|   |     |     |
+---+-----+-----+
```

What I am having trouble with is reading the text to a 2D list.  Whenever I try it either creates a list of one very long string like this:

This code:

```
    with open(fileName) as f:
        grid = f.read().split("/n")
```

Gives this output:

```
['+---+-----+-----+\n|   |     |     |\n|   |     |     |\n|   |     +=====+\n+---+     |  |  |\n|   |     |  |  |\n|   +-+   +=====+\n|   | |   |     |\n|   | +-+ |     |\n|   |   | |     |\n|   |   +-+     |\n|   |     |_____|\n|   |     |     |\n+---+-----+-----+']
```

or something where it deletes spaces:

Where this code:

```
with open(fileName) as f:
    grid = f.read().split()
```

Gives this:

```
['+---+-----+-----+', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '+=====+', '+---+', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '+-+', '+=====+', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '+-+', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '+-+', '|', '|', '|', '|_____|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '+---+-----+-----+']
```

What I need is a 2D list that includes EVERY character, (yes, even spaces) so that I may manipulate each one at a later point.  This is what I'm looking for:

```
[['+','-','-','-','+','-','-','-','-','-','+','-','-','-','-','-','+']
['|',' ',' ',' ','|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','+']
['|',' ',' ',' ','|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','+']
.... etc
```

Sorry if this is easy, I'm fairly new to programming.  Also I have looked through other questions on here and couldn't find one similar to what I needed, so sorry in advance if this has already been answered.

Comment: Can you post your code to fix it...

Comment: If this is a school project, I'd wager that all the skills you need are in your course notes. Actually attempt writing some code and then if that doesn't work come back with a clear problem, not just "how do I do this?"

Comment: I've tried a bunch of things I learned in class and on here and i can't seem to to get it right.  We learned how to write to text files and read them but nothing like this.

Comment: `grid = f.read().split("/n")` - you may want to double check this line.

Comment: yup I'm dumb and used /n instead of \n.  Also could have used splitlines()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
>>> with open('file') as f:
...     lines = f.read().splitlines()

>>> [list(i) for i in lines]
[['+', '-', '-', '-', '+', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '+', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '+'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | '],
 [' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | '],
 [' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' = ', ' = ', ' = ', ' = ', ' = ', '+'],
 ['+', '-', '-', '-', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' ', ' |', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '-', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', ' = ', ' = ', ' = ', ' = ', ' = ', '+'],
 [' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | '],
 [' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', '+', '-', '+', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | '],
 [' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' |', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '+', '-', '+', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', ' | '],
 [' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' | ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['+', '-', '-', '-', '+', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '+', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '+']]
```

Comment: This is close but I need each line to be a separate list, while "grid" is a list of all the lines, which will let me call a specific element in the overall grid. Basically I need to use coordinates to look at each individual character of the overall grid

Comment: Huh.  I'm trying that out but its not separating each character

Comment: Isn't that your expect output?

Comment: Yea your output is what I want. Ok so when i put '[list(i) for i in lines]' into my code then 'print(lines)' it doesn't change the output.  but if i do 'print([list(i) for i in lines])' then it prints the desired output.  How do i change the actual lines variable to stay that way?

Comment: No, it doesn't change the `lines`. It creates/return a new list. So you should use `lines = [list(i) for i in lines]` and then `print(lines)`.

Comment: ah ok I've got it now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TylerSturtz: Glad I could help :). If you think an answer is useful, please remember accept it. Check our [tour] and [help] for more details ;)

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is a school project, I am intentionally avoiding posting the full solution, so here are some hints that should be sufficient to figure it out:

- `"/n"` is not a newline. Study the output string to see what newline *is*. This way, you are splitting on something that is not found in the string, which gives you a one-element array of everything.
- `.split()` splits on all whitespace. Not what you want. The first attempt is better, but see above.
- When you split the file into lines, you need to split each line into characters. `list(line)` will do that for a single line. Study either list comprehensions or the `map` function to figure out how to apply `list` on every line in the split result.

Answer (score 0):

read line by line, as:

```
for line in f:
    print(line)
```

You might not need to create a list from a string as you can use index [] on string directly.